# Let $V$ be a vector space over $C$ with dimension $n.$ Prove that if $V$ is now regarded as a vector space over $R,$ then $\dim V =2n.$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $C$ with dimension $n.$ Prove that if $V$ is now regarded as a vector space over $R,$ then $\dim V =2n.$

I tried solving the problem as follows:

Given, $\dim V =n$ when $V$ is vector space over $C$ and so, we assume $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ to be a basis  for $V$ over $C.$

Claim: $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ is a basis  for $V$ over $\Bbb R.$

Let $v\in V.$ Now, $\exists$ scalars $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$ in $C$ such that $c_1b_1+...+c_nb_n=v.$ Now, $\exists d_1,d_2,...,d_n,d_{n+1},d_{n+2},...,d_{2n}\in \Bbb R,$ such that $c_1=d_1+id_{n+1},c_2=d_2+id_{n+2},...,c_n=d_n+id_{2n}.$ This means $$(d_1+id_{n+1})b_1+(d_2+id_{n+2})b_2+...+(d_n+id_{2n})b_n=v\implies d_1b_1+d_2b_2+...+d_nb_n+id_{n+1}b_1+id_{n+2}b_2+...+id_{2n}b_n=v\implies d_1b_1+d_2b_2+...+d_nb_n+d_{n+1}(ib_1)+d_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+d_{2n}(ib_n)=v.$$ Hence,  $\exists d_1,d_2,...,d_n,d_{n+1},d_{n+2},...,d_{2n}\in \Bbb R,$ such that $ d_1b_1+d_2b_2+...+d_nb_n+d_{n+1}(ib_1)+d_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+d_{2n}(ib_n)=v.$ Since, $v\in V$ is an arbitrary vector, we can say that, $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ generates $V$ when $V$  is considered to be a vector space over $\Bbb R.$

Again,if $\exists a_1,a_2,...,a_{2n}$ in $R$ such that  $$a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+a_{n+1}(ib_1)+a_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+a_{2n}(ib_n)=0,$$ we can say, $$a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+(ia_{n+1})b_1+(ia_{n+2})b_2+...+(ia_{2n})b_n=0.$$ This means,  $$(a_1+ia_{n+1})b_1+(a_2+ia_{n+2})b_2+...+(a_n+ia_{2n})b_n=0$$ and hence, $a_1=a_2=...=a_{2n}=0$ for $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ is a basis  for $V$ over $C.$ This proves,  $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ is linearly independent subset of $V.$

Finally, we can say that,  $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ is a basis for $V$ over $\Bbb R.$

Hence, $\dim V =2n,$ when $V$ is  regarded as a vector space over $R.$

---

However, I feel that something is wrong with my solution. The part where I wrote, " Again,if $\exists a_1,a_2,...,a_{2n}$ in $R$ such that  $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+a_{n+1}(ib_1)+a_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+a_{2n}(ib_n)=0,$ we can say, $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+(ia_{n+1})b_1+(ia_{n+2})b_2+...+(ia_{2n})b_n=0$ " seems ambiguous to me. This is beacause, I am not sure whether $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+a_{n+1}(ib_1)+a_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+a_{2n}(ib_n)=0,$ and $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+(ia_{n+1})b_1+(ia_{n+2})b_2+...+(ia_{2n})b_n=0$ are the same thing.

We must not forget that $V$ is now being regarded as a vector space over $\Bbb R.$ Although, $ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ makes sense for they are just the vectors in $V$ ( we can say, this because scalar multiplication when $V$ is a vector space over $C$ is closed) but the symbol, $i$ does not make any sense now that $V$ is being regarded as a vector space over $\Bbb R.$ Precisely, because of this reason I don't think that we can write, say, $a_{n+1}(ib_1)=(ia_{n+1})b_1.$ And this in fact, makes my proof incorrect in my opinion, for then, we can't conclude, $(a_1+ia_{n+1})b_1+(a_2+ia_{n+2})b_2+...+(a_n+ia_{2n})b_n=0$ from $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+a_{n+1}(ib_1)+a_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+a_{2n}(ib_n)=0.$

The problem would have been solved  if we could've concluded $(a_1+ia_{n+1})b_1+(a_2+ia_{n+2})b_2+...+(a_n+ia_{2n})b_n=0$ from $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n+a_{n+1}(ib_1)+a_{n+2}(ib_2)+...+a_{2n}(ib_n)=0.$

Is there a way to fix the issue?

Comment: If $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ is a basis  for $V$ over $\mathbb{C},$ the entries of new basis $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ are complex and need not be real. So why do you make such a claim?

Comment: @Explorer There is no well-defined meaning of the term "complex" associated with vectors of $V$. The word complex or real in this case makes sense only if you are talking about scalars in $C$ or $R$ as the case maybe. So, the sentence, "the entries of new basis $b_1,b_2,...,b_n,ib_1,ib_2,...,ib_n$ are complex and need not be real" makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

See, it is more of a logical consistency and notational issue than an algebraic one. Firstly, you assume the existence of the vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{C}$. So when you suddenly remove a certain number of scalars, then suddenly some vectors (like $ib_{1},...,ib_{n}$) fail to make sense notationally. For example, consider just the vector space $V$ to be of dimension $1$ i.e. $span_{\Bbb{C}}(\{b_{1}\})$. Then suddenly when you remove the element $i$ from your ground field then $i\cdot b_{1}$ fails to make sense(notationally) when you regard $V$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ (i.e. one where potentially, elements of the form $iv$ may not exist for certain $v$).

A workaround is that the scalar multiplication $\phi(c,v)=cv$ is a map from $\Bbb{C}\times V\to V$ and this map satisfies distributive properties. i.e. $\phi(d,\phi(c,v))=\phi(dc,v)$ among others. And when you are viewing $V$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$, you are restricting $\phi$ to act only on $\Bbb{R}\subseteq \Bbb{C}$.

So when you are writing that $v=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}b_{j}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j+n}(ib_{j})$ ,you are basically writing $v=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\phi|_{\Bbb{R}}(a_{j},b_{j})+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\phi|_{\Bbb{R}}(a_{j+n},(\phi (i,b_{j}))$ (here the outer $\phi|_{\Bbb{R}}$, is restricted as a map from $\Bbb{R}$ and $\phi(i,b_{j})$ is a well defined element in the vector space(set) $V$  over $\Bbb{C}$ which you assumed to be existent).

And your modified claim becomes $\{b_{1},...,b_{n},\phi(i,b_{1}),...,\phi(i,b_{n})\}$ where all the elements are bonafide elements of $V$ (as viewed as a SET) are linearly independent and forms a basis for $V$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ with respect to  the restricted scalar multiplication operator $\phi|_{\Bbb{R}}:\Bbb{R}\times V\to V$ as I gave above.

And then by invoking the structure of $V$ over $\Bbb{C}$ which you apriori assumed that it existed, you can say $v=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\phi(a_{j}+ia_{j+n},b_{j})$ by distributive properties of $\phi$ as  a map from $V\times\Bbb{C}\to V$

and now you can conlcude that $a_{j}+ia_{n+j}=0$ by the linear independence of $b_{i}$ as given by the structure on $V$. This forces $a_{j}=0=a_{n+j}$ by properties of the complex field.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. At first you regard

$$a_1b_1+\ldots + a_nb_n+a_{n+1}(ib_1)+\ldots+a_{2n}(ib_n)$$

as an element of the *real* vectors space spanned by $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n,ib_1,\ldots ib_n\}$. Since this is zero in the real vector space it will continue to be zero if we regard this expression as living the *complex* vector space spanned by $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n,ib_1,\ldots ib_n\}$. Once you regard it in this complex vector space it is fine to commute the $i$'s and the $a_j$'s and the rest of your argument goes through to show that all the $a_j$'s are zero and hence your set is linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.